# SharePoint 2010 - The account in User Information is not up to date with Active Directory

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-property

I'm running a 2010 SharePoint environment and have encountered a problem in the User Information list.

Previously a user logged in with username:

```
domain\JackSh
```

But his accountname has been changed to username:

```
domain\JackShi
```

The problem I'm facing now is that his Account name is not being updated in SharePoint. When he clicks My Settings and lands on the User Information page, it still shows his old login name.

I can view his - incorrect - User information on the page:

```
http://<SiteCollectionUrl>/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx
```

Does anyone know how I can force an update of his account name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the account by running the `stsadm -o migrateuser` command:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953131

This will rename the userid in the UserInfo table in your content databases to the new userid.

If that doesn't work try looking at your user profile service application. Every hour a timer job runs that syncs user information from this service application to your content databases. The following article lists some common causes & resolutions that you can try:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2388988

Comment: Do you know what the parameter -ignoresidhistory does?

Comment: That's useful if you want to replace a user with a completely different user or a user from another domain. This should not be necessary in your case. More info on the migrate user command at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262141(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I executed the command: stsadm.exe -o migrateuser -oldlogin domain\jacksh -newlogin domain\jackshi and received the following notification: New user account does not have valid SID history. I'm going to let the user try and login first

Comment: Your situation is described in this knowledge base article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953131 // You can try running with ignoresidhistory, that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: I'm afraid this command didn't solve my problem. The account name still has not been updated. When I try to run the command again, I receive the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Do you have another way of trying to resolve this?

Comment: I've added to my answer to check for user profile service application to content database sync issues

Answer (score 2):

In addition to merging the user profiles in Thomas Vochten's response using stsadm -o migrateuser and ensuring the user profile sync is running as mentioned by QuinnJohns, you will want to make sure that the content database's current status is set to online.  If it is set to offline, the timer job that syncs the user information list will not run for those site collections.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to make sure that the user profile synchronization service is started/active.

http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee721049.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Note that there's another "extreme" option that has worked for some people as described in [this blog post](http://sharepointbergen.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/old-or-wrong-user-display-name-is.html). To summarize:

1. Locate the user in the site collection at `http://<SiteCollectionUrl>/<path>/_layouts/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0`
2. Click the link to "Delete user from site collection"
3. Add the user into some SharePoint group in this same site collection

*Warning!: If you do this, you are in fact removing SharePoint's memory of that user account -- so any place where you granted them permissions, etc. will all be forgotten.*

(I include this answer for completion, not because I necessarily recommend it.)